# How to get timestamp when transaction is committed (or completed) in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I need to calculate the difference between "the timestamp when transaction is submitted" and "the timestamp when transaction is committed". Is it possible to get the tx committed (or completed) timestamp in fabric?

I tried to use Hyperledger Explorer running on my composer channel. I can see tx timestamp inside the block. But I am not sure whether it is creation or committing timestamp. Also, can I convert explorer timestamp to ISO 8601 format?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp you see is the endorsement time timestamp, you can get access to it during chaincode invocation by using following API:

```
// GetTxTimestamp returns the timestamp when the transaction was created. This
// is taken from the transaction ChannelHeader, therefore it will indicate the
// client's timestamp, and will have the same value across all endorsers.
GetTxTimestamp() (*timestamp.Timestamp, error)
```

If you would like to compute the difference between two events, I'd suggest to leverage events hub to get direct notification of transaction being committed. You basically need to subscribe to events waiting for your transaction then you will be able to compute the difference, note you need to compute average request RTT to deduct it from the final result to get more accurate evaluation. To see how you can get subscribed to events you can see an example here [(Deprecated)block_listener.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.2/examples/events/block-listener).

Comment: yes, please follow instructions from README.md file (available in same folder)

Comment: Hello Artem, I am able to print the received tx from the channel. But I could not see timestamp (for when block is added to ledger or tx is committed) in the block event. Do i need to add extra line of code in block-listener.go inorder to print time whenever event occurs? Also, if this the case, can you tell me how can i print ISO 8601 time in Go?

Comment: what I've meant to say, is that you will start measure the time in the client code before sending transaction and stop the time upon event receive of corresponding transaction being committed

Comment: to your second question wrt ISO 8601, this is fairly simple with     fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700"))

Comment: Hi @ArtemBarger is this timestamp only available at chaincode invocation  or it's also registered after on the ledger ?

Comment: @ArtemBarger  I am using GetTxTimestamp as a seed for a random number but I don't want this seed to be registered on the ledger

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I changed blockchain-explorer/main.js code to convert time format.

```
app.post("/api/tx/getinfo", function(req, res) {

let  txid = req.body.txid
if( txid != '0' ){
query.getTransactionByID(peer,ledgerMgr.getCurrChannel(),txid,org).then(response_payloads=>{

    var header = response_payloads['transactionEnvelope']['payload']['header']
    var data = response_payloads['transactionEnvelope']['payload']['data']
    var signature = response_payloads['transactionEnvelope']['signature'].toString("hex")
    res.send({
        'tx_id':header.channel_header.tx_id,
        'timestamp':header.channel_header.timestamp,
        'channel_id':header.channel_header.channel_id,
        'type':header.channel_header.type,
    })
})

}else{
    res.send({ })
}});
```

TO

```
app.post("/api/tx/getinfo", function(req, res) {

let  txid = req.body.txid
if( txid != '0' ){
query.getTransactionByID(peer,ledgerMgr.getCurrChannel(),txid,org).then(response_payloads=>{

    var header = response_payloads['transactionEnvelope']['payload']['header']
    var data = response_payloads['transactionEnvelope']['payload']['data']
    var signature = response_payloads['transactionEnvelope']['signature'].toString("hex")
    res.send({
        'tx_id':header.channel_header.tx_id,
        'timestamp':new Date(header.channel_header.timestamp).toISOString(),
        'channel_id':header.channel_header.channel_id,
        'type':header.channel_header.type,
    })
})

}else{
    res.send({ })
}});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I converted the tx timestamp (presented in the block) into ISO format but i think, this timestamp is not the tx committed time (or when tx completed). It is the same when tx is created. I could not use this to calculate the difference. Also, the converted time in ISO does not show milliseconds.